# Find source of outgoing traffic

Tags: webserver, malware

My web server has been infected by a bot that is brute-force attacking Wordpress sites.

I can see the outgoing POST requests and their content, but I am not able to find the script, pid or user that are generating these requests.
Of course my goal is to remove that malicious software.

Do you know any way to find where is that outgoing traffic being generated?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want netstat. If it is not installed, open your terminal and...

```
sudo apt-get install netstat
```

Then:

```
netstat -man
```

Or, for a more quick way this should give you more information than you want:

```
netstat -a -v
```

Depending on how deep you want to go then Wireshark is an option as well.

Comment: Thanks, though it doesn't solve my problem, at least it shows me the right direction. This command helped me: `netstat -npt` it displays the PID/Program name for a connection

Comment: @JuanchoRamone Yeah, you can get the program number and also HTOP comes in handy at this point. Wireshark is a bit complex but also workable.